# ¿Cómo insertar usuario en BD MySQL a través de una interfaz Java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que a través de una interfaz un usuario meta sus datos y se inserte en la base de datos para que aparezca como registrado.
He hecho una clase de gestionRegistro tal que:

```
public Usuario registrarUsuario(Usuario usu) {
        
        Usuario usuario = null;
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stm = null;
        try {
            
            con = Conexion.conectar();
            
            String sql = "INSERT INTO USUARIO('usuario', 'clave', 'apellidos', 'dni') VALUES ( ? ,? , ? , ?)";
            
            stm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            
            stm.setString(1, usu.getUsuario());
            stm.setString(2, usu.getClave());
            stm.setString(3, usu.getApellidos());
            stm.setString(4, usu.getDni());
            
            stm.executeUpdate(sql);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error al insertar el USUARIO");
        }
```

Siendo el método registrar en la interfaz:

```
protected void registrarse() {
        
        String usuario = txtNombre.getText();
        String apellidos = txtApellidos.getText();
        String dni = txtDni.getText();
        String clave = String.valueOf(pssClave.getPassword());
        
        gestionRegistro regCli = new gestionRegistro(); 
        
        Usuario usuario2 = new Usuario();
        
        usuario2.setUsuario(usuario);
        usuario2.setApellidos(apellidos);
        usuario2.setDni(dni);
        usuario2.setClave(clave);
        
        Usuario usu = regCli.registrarUsuario(usuario2);
```

No me da ningún fallo pero no hace la sentencia SQL, por lo tanto no me registra al usuario a la base de datos, y no consigo saber por qué, ya que la sentencia creo que está bien hecha.
Adjunto el código de la clase con la que realizo la conexion a la base de datos. Gracias

```
public class Conexion {
    
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gestionhoteles";
    private static final String USUARIO = "root";
    private static final String CLAVE = "";
    
    public static Connection conectar() {
        
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USUARIO, CLAVE);
            System.out.println("CONNECT OK");
            

        } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Error con la conexión a la  BBDD");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
        return con;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola ,es importante revisar si en la consola se muestra algún mensaje de error, agrégalo a tu pregunta. Veo que usas localhost por lo tanto seguramente solo puedes probar en tu pc.

Comment: No muestra ningún mensaje de error en la consola ...

Comment: No se muestra el error `Error al insertar el USUARIO` que tienes en el catch? `executeUpdate` retorna un `int` y no lo estás recibiendo. Tampoco cierras la conexión ni el stm nunca en algún `finally` y eso puede terminar como un leak de memoria. ¿Puedes ver haciendo un e.printStackTrace en registrarUsuario para que sea un poco más descriptivo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece estar bien tu código, salvo algunas observaciones:

1. public Usuario registrarUsuario(Usuario usu) //debería ser de tipo void porque no va devolver un objeto de tipo Usuario.
2. En el método `registrarse`, está mal la siguiente linea de código

> Usuario usu = regCli.registrarUsuario(usuario2);

El método `registrarUsuario` ya recibe como argumento un objeto de tipo Usuario y no tiene sentido que devuelva algún valor, así es como debería quedar la linea de código `regCli.registrarUsuario(usuario2);`

Te brindo algunas mejoras a tu código inicial.

```
public class Conexion {

private static final String BD= "gestionhoteles";
private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+BD;
private static final String USUARIO = "root";
private static final String CLAVE = "";

public static Connection conectar() {
    
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USUARIO, CLAVE);
        
        if (conn!=null){
            System.out.println("Conectado a la base de datos ["+BD+"]");
        }
        return con;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error con la conexión a la  BBDD");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
   }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
         System.err.println(e.getMessage());
   }
    
    return null;
 }
}
```

Cuando vas a realizar una modificación en tu base de datos siempre haz uso de  [TRANSACCIONES](https://www.purocodigo.net/articulo/transacciones-en-mysql).

```
public void registrarUsuario(Usuario usu) {
    Connection con = Conexion.conectar();
    PreparedStatement stm = null;
    
    try {
        //se deshabilita el modo de confirmación automática de la BD
        con.setAutoCommit(false);        
        
        String sql = "INSERT INTO USUARIO('usuario', 'clave', 'apellidos', 'dni') VALUES ( ? ,? , ? , ?)";
        
        stm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        
        stm.setString(1, usu.getUsuario());
        stm.setString(2, usu.getClave());
        stm.setString(3, usu.getApellidos());
        stm.setString(4, usu.getDni());
        
        stm.executeUpdate(sql);
        
       //se indica que se deben aplicar los cambios en la base de datos
        con.commit();
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
            if(con!=null)
            {
                System.out.println("Rollback");
                try {
                    //deshace todos los cambios realizados en los datos
                    con.rollback();
                } catch (SQLException ex1) {
                    System.err.println( "No se pudo deshacer" + ex1.getMessage() );    
                }
            }                
        }finally{
            System.out.println( "cierra conexion a la base de datos" );    
            try {
                if(stm!=null) stm.close();
                if(con!=null) con.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.err.println( ex.getMessage() );    
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: Gracias Joshin por las mejoras en el codigo !!!

Answer (score 1):

Yo te puedo compartir un ejemplo funcionando, espero que te pueda ayudar.
// into package Config

```
public class Conexion {
    
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase";
    String user = "root";
    String pass = "";
    Connection con;
    
    public Conexion(){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error is ->  " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    public Connection getConnection(){
        return con;
    }
    
}
```

//package modeloDAO

```
public class UsuarioDAO implements UsuarioCRUD {
    Conexion bdC = new Conexion();
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    
    UsuarioM userM = new UsuarioM();

public boolean create(UsuarioM user) {
        LocalDateTime hoy = LocalDateTime.now();        
         String sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (email, password, tipo, created) VALUES ('"+user.getEmail()+"', '"+user.getPassword()+"', '"+user.getTipo()+"', '"+hoy+"' )";
        try{
           con = bdC.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.executeUpdate(sql);
            
        }catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

//serverlet do post

```
String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        int tipo = Integer.parseInt(  request.getParameter("tipo"));
        
        UsuarioDAO  query = new UsuarioDAO();
        UsuarioM user = new UsuarioM();
        
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setTipo(tipo);
        
        boolean estado = query.create(user);
        
        sesion = request.getSession();
        
        if(estado){
           sesion.setAttribute("bien", "se guardao correctamente");
           response.sendRedirect("Usuarios");
        }else{
            sesion.setAttribute("error", "No se pudo guardar");
           response.sendRedirect("UsuarioNew");
        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Carlos !!!

Comment: Recuerda que la respuesta debe ser útil no solo para el OP (autor de la pregunta), sino para los demás miembros de la comunidad. Por lo tanto, agrega una breve explicación de lo que hace el código. Lee [answer].